# Existence of an illegitimate conglomerate of isomorphisms of $\mathbf{Set}$ onto itself

Tags: category-theory

Definitions: A conglomerate $\mathbf{K}$ is *legitimate* if there exists a class $\mathbf{C}$, and a surjection $f:\mathbf{C}\to\mathbf{K}$, or alternatively, if there exists an injection $f:\mathbf{K}\to\mathbf{C}$.

My intuition behind this question is that the conglomerate $F=\{ f:\mathbf{Set}\to\mathbf{Set}\big| |f(U)| = |U|\forall U\in\mathbf{Set}\}$ is somehow bigger than any class can be, but I can't find out how to formalize this.

Comment: Are you using the terms as defined in *The Joy of Cats* or some other source? Have you tried a diagonalization argument to show an injection does not exist?

Comment: Think just about the action of the isomorphism on the (proper) class of singleton sets. There is an illegitimate conglomerate of bijections of this class with itself.